How to upgrade Jenkins which is running in a docker container withour losing any data?
So the problem is my Jenkins is running on a docker container and that Jenkins needs update. So that cannot happen while this Jenkins is running. If I download the latest Jenkins image , I will have to spin up a new container and new container will not contain the jobs that I had in the previous one. Can someone help here ?

Didn't you not configure volumes you need volumes so when you update you don't lose your data :
docker-compose.yaml :
services:
  jenkins-controller:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk17
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
    restart: always
volumes:
  jenkins-data:


then run:
docker-compose up

jenkins-data volume shall keep your data so when you update nothing will change under the /var/jenkins_home directory
let's say you want to update to lts jdk 21
docker-compose.yaml :
services:
  jenkins-controller:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk21
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
    restart: always
volumes:
  jenkins-data:


then run :
docker-compose up

and you will have the new jenkins lts (long term support) with jdk 21 (java tool kit)(no lost data)
in short, just change the tag and rerun docker-compose up, this is the simplest way (simpler than the command line version.)
